# Generator failing with NoneType error

Tags: python, list, generator

I am making a text RPG, and one of the game commands is `statistics`. It prints all of the player's statistics, one of them being `Defense Strength`, which is determined by the defensive items in the second and third (1, 2) slots of the player's inventory. All items in the game are instances of an `item` class and have the attribute `Str` (strength). The Player's inventory is a list with 5 slots (which never changes) and empty slots are represented with `None`'s.

To print the player's Defense Strength, for every item in the Inventory list, if it is not None, or is True in a boolean statement, I want to add its `Str` value (always an int) to create a total sum.

This is what I have:

```
print('- Defense Strength:', sum(i.Str for i in Inventory[1:3] if Inventory[i]))
```

However this fails with the error `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not NoneType`
How can I fix this!?

PS: Even though I am only iterating over 2 indices, I want to create this statement in only 1 line because it is quite simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `if i`, instead of `if  Inventory[i]`, you are trying to index using a `NoneType`

You are already iterating over `Inventory` items so  `if i` will filter the `NoneTypes`.

You are basically doing:

```
l = [1,2,None,None]
for i in l:
    if l[i]: # trying to access list using None as an index
        print (i)

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not NoneType
```

When you should be doing:

```
for i in l:
    if i: # check if element is not None
       print (i)
1 # prints values that are not None
2
```